# error: used struct type value where scalar is required

Tags: c

I am creating a program which takes an input and opens a text file and changes words to lower or upper case depending on what the user wants. When I compile the program I gets the following error:

```
22:11: error: used struct type value where scalar is required
30:11: error: used struct type value where scalar is required

  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 int main(void) {
  3
  4         char choice;
  5         char fileName;
  6         char newFileName;
  7         int i = 0;
  8
  9         printf("Change Case \n");
 10         printf("============\n");
 11         printf("Case (U for upper, L for lower) : ");
 12         scanf(" %c", &choice);
 13         printf("Name of the original file : oldFile.txt \n");
 14         printf("Name of the updated file : newFile.txt \n");
 15
 16         FILE *fp = NULL;
 17
 18         fp = fopen("oldFile.txt", "a");
 19
 20         if (fp != NULL && choice == 'L') {
 21
 22                 while ( fp[i] ) {
 23
 24                         putchar(tolower(fp[i]));
 25                         i++;
 26                 }
 27         }
 28         else if (fp != NULL && choice == 'U') {
 29
 30                 while ( fp[i] ) {
 31
 32                         putchar(toupper(fp[i]));
 33                         i++;
 34                 }
 35         }
 36         else {
 37
 38                 printf("ERROR: No proper choice was made \n");
 39         }
 40 }
```

Comment: What is `fp[i]` supposed to be?

Comment: why are you indexing fp?  It is not an array. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/

Comment: Have you read any documentation for `fopen` ?

Comment: fp is a file pointer. if you increment fp (i.e. fp[i]), you are moving that file pointer to point to another memory location and you would get some random value currently stored in the memory location. You might want to try `while (fgets (...))` which is the function you want to use if you are trying to stream the text from your text file.

Comment: Do not post line numbered source code, it looks ugly and is a pain to compile.

Answer (score 3):

`fp` is a *file pointer*,  not an array of whats in your file. [Have a look at use of `fopen` in a tutorial.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm)

You will need to use something like [`fgets`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) to read your file into a buffer. You can also use [`fgetc`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm) to read your file one character at a time.

Answer (score 1):

wrong way accessing file pointer `fp`. It is an pointer to a file not a array character or string. Each time a file is opened, the system places the file pointer at the beginning of the file, which is offset zero.

Close the opened file every time after processing using `fclose(fP)`;

sample example code snippet of using file pointer.

```
int c;
fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
   while(1)
   {
      c = fgetc(fp);// or fgets as per the usage
      if( c==EOF)
      { 
        //Exit
      }
      // your code 
   }
   fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Make `c` an `int` and check for end of file idiomatically: `if (c == EOF)`.  `feof()` is error prone.

Comment: frof() is not wrong and it doesn't mean you need to down vote.

Comment: Please do not suggest the use of `feof()` to a beginner, you are not helping him.  Also define `c` as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The file pointer is not an array... consider using fgetc/fgets. `fp[i]` doesn't give you the i-th byte of the file. fgetc will let you iterate over the bytes of the file and return EOF when you're at the end.

See the documentation for fgetc [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetc).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to acquire strings from txt. There are many other ways

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("oldFile.txt", "r");
    char str[1024];
    while(fgets(str, 1024, fp)!=NULL) {     //acquire strings from oldFile.txt through fgets() which returns a pointer. NULL is returned at the end of file
        printf("%s", str); //just an example
    }
}
```